# How to return multiple rows from result set object to send servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a class it retrieve number of rows from database but here i return result set object to servlet class and based on those rows i need to display in table when i retrieve table it shows single row only but when i execute same query it shows in Database having two rows may be i didn't return result set object properly can anyone help me to retrieve all the all records from database.

Servlet :

```
 WorkAreaClass wa=new WorkAreaClass();            
               ResultSet resultSet = wa.workarea(User);        
                if(resultSet.next())
                {                   
                 table(resultSet,out);              
                }
```

Comment: No, there's no way to return a reference to a `ResultSet` that would somehow cut the amount of rows by half.

Comment: suppose you use `resultSet.last()` followed by `resultSet.getRow()` to get the row count the query return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `if(resultSet.next())` before you start to iterate the resultset. After that you'll be on the first row. Then when you enter your `while(rs.next())` loop, the cursor is moved to the *second* row.

You can convert the `while` loop into a `do-while` and it won't skip the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose @kayaman solution is correct.

Simply your table should be like this.

```
public int table( ResultSet rs, PrintWriter out)throws Exception
    {
        int rowcount=0;
        out.println("<P ALIGN='center'><TABLE BORDER=1>");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        // table header
         out.println("<TR>");
         for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
               out.println("<TH>" + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i + 1) + "</TH>");
        }
         out.println("</TR>");
        // the data

        do { 
             rowcount++;
             out.println("<TR>");
             for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {                
                  out.println("<TD>" + rs.getString(i + 1) + "</TD>");              
             }           
             out.println("</TR>");  
        } while(rs.next());

        out.println("</TABLE></P>");        
        return rowcount;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JDBCRowSet https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcrowset.html
here is short demo:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
           ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
           ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from COFFEES");
JdbcRowSetImpl jdbcRs = new JdbcRowSetImpl(rs);
```